# Trying to make div move on screen on keydown

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to make a game where the player has to navigate a mouse through a maze to find the block of cheese. I'm having some trouble getting the div to move how I want it to. The problem is when you press the down arrow key (the key i'm using to test it) it wont keep going down by increments of ten like I want it to. I've tried loops, the whole shebang but I just can't figure out how to make it work.

```
document.onkeydown = function(key){
    if (key.keyCode == 38){
        console.log("up");
    } else if (key.keyCode == 39){
        console.log("right");
    } else if (key.keyCode == 37){
        console.log("left");
    } else if (key.keyCode == 40){
        mouse.style.top = 10 + "px";
    };
};
```

Comment: I'll take a look, if it solves my problem ill close the question, thanks.

Comment: Can you point in your code where you increment anything? I see only if statements and one  assignment.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha Looks like the answers are in jQuery, not vanilla javascript.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That's my exact problem, I don't know how to increment each time the person clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Player` object and modify it's `x` and `y` properties.
Create also a `K` object to set to a boolean the currently used **keys** numbers.
Than inside a loop like `requestAnimationFrame` move the player:

```js
const Player = {
  el: document.getElementById('mouse'),
  x: 200,
  y: 100,
  speed: 2,
  move() {
    // If no collision with map or tiles... (TODO!)
    this.el.style.transform = `translate(${this.x}px, ${this.y}px)`;
  }
};
 
const K = {
  fn(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const k = ev.which;
    if (k >= 37 && k <= 40) K[k] = ev.type === "keydown"; // If is arrow
  }
};
  
const update = () => {
    // 1 / Math.sqrt(2) = 0.7071.. (Diagonal)
    let dist = K[38] && (K[37] || K[39]) || K[40] && (K[37] || K[39]) ? 0.707 : 1;
    dist *= Player.speed;
    if (K[37]) Player.x -= dist;
    if (K[38]) Player.y -= dist;
    if (K[39]) Player.x += dist;
    if (K[40]) Player.y += dist;
    Player.move();
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', K.fn);
document.addEventListener('keyup', K.fn);

(function engine() {
  update();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(engine);
}());
```

```css
#mouse{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;  top: 0;
  width: 20px;  height: 20px;
  background: #000;  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
Click here to focus, and use arrows
<div id="mouse"></div>
```

---

A **simpler** example, which moves the element by *Npx* steps and repeats as long as you keep the key pressed (just like typing) would be:

```js
const Player = {
  el: document.getElementById('mouse'),
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  step: 10,
  move() {
    this.el.style.transform = `translate(${this.x}px, ${this.y}px)`;
  }
};

const keysHandler = (ev) => {
  const k = ev.which;
  if (k>=37 && k<=40) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ({
      '37' () {Player.x -= Player.step},
      '38' () {Player.y -= Player.step},
      '39' () {Player.x += Player.step},
      '40' () {Player.y += Player.step},
    }[k]());
    Player.move();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', keysHandler);
```

```css
#mouse{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;  top: 0;
  width: 20px;  height: 20px;
  background: #000;  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
Click here to focus, and use arrows
<div id="mouse"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting it to 10 every time, use `split` to get the value first:

```
else if (key.keyCode == 40){
    mouse.style.top = parseInt(mouse.style.top.split("px")[0]) + 10 + "px";
}
```

Comment: Jack always giving me exactly what I need.

Comment: No problem - learning how to code is 10% questions, 90% answers, and 5% experimenting. I'm always glad to help.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, I couldn't tell you why though Ill have to do research into `parseInt()` and `split` @Jack Bashford

Answer (score 0):

Even though other answer used `parseInt`, it's better to keep variables inside the code

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

document.onkeydown = function(key){
    if (key.keyCode == 38){
        y -= 10;
    } else if (key.keyCode == 39){
        x += 10;
    } else if (key.keyCode == 37){
        x -= 10;
    } else if (key.keyCode == 40){
        y += 10;
    };
    
    document.getElementById("block").style.left = x+"px";
    document.getElementById("block").style.top = y+"px";
};
```

```css
#block
{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
```